# Найти максимальную по длине последовательность цифр в строке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо найти максимальную по длине последовательность цифр в строке.

```
lists = []   # Создание пустого массива
inputString = input("Введите строку: ") #Ввод исходной строки
xArr = list(inputString) # Разбитие строки на массив из элементов строки
MaxInt = 0 # Максимальная длина чисел
index = 0 # индекс массива xArr
while index <= len(xArr): # Пока индекс меньше равен длине Массива
  if type(xArr[index]) == int: # если индекс равен числовому типу 
    MaxInt = MaxInt + 1 # инкремент Длины чисел
    index += 1 # инкремент индекса
  if type(xArr[index + 1]) == str or index == len(xArr): # если след символ 
   # строки символ или конец строки
    lists.append(MaxInt) # добавление в конец массива с макс значениями 
     #текущую макс длину цифр
    MaxInt = 0 # обнуляю макс значение
    break # останавливаю цикл

print(max(lists))  # Макс значение из массива с макс значениями
```

Comment: И что код? Не находит? Находит, но не то?

Comment: В последнем print выводит 0 хотя, элемент в конец массива я добавляю с помощью .append

Comment: Значит добавляется 0.  Вообще для таких проблем придумали отладку. Напечатай список lists. То ли там лежит, что ожидается. Если нет, печатай промежуточные значения в ходе выполнения.

Comment: Кстати, на выходе из input всегда строка, даже если кажется, что это цифра. Проблема именно в этом.

Comment: вот что сразу видно - `if type(xArr[index]) == int` никогда: у вас на входе список из символов; если у вас список до длины массива, то `xArr[index + 1]` тут будет слишком большой индекс

Answer (score 5):

Это можно очень просто решить регулярными выражениями.

Регулярное выражение `\d+` ищет последовательности цифр, а `re.findall` вернет строки с результатом.

Останется список строк превратить в список длин строк и получить максимальное значение.

Пример:

```
import re

text = input("Введите строку: ")
items = re.findall('\d+', text)
max_len = max(len(x) for x in items)
print(max_len)
```

Консоль:

```
Введите строку: 12 abcsd232 df12124 5555555
7
```

---

**UPD.**

Через цикл:

```
text = '12 abcsd232 df12124 5555555'
max_len = 0
cur_len = 0

for c in text:
    if c in '0123456789':
        cur_len += 1
    else:
        if cur_len > max_len:
            max_len = cur_len
        cur_len = 0

if cur_len > max_len:
    max_len = cur_len

print(max_len)  # 7
```

Или:

```
text = '12 abcsd232 df12124 5555555'
max_len = 0
cur_len = 0

for i in range(len(text)):
    c = text[i]
    if c in '0123456789':
        cur_len += 1
    elif cur_len > max_len:
        max_len = cur_len
        cur_len = 0

    # Конец строки
    if i == len(text) - 1 and cur_len > max_len:
        max_len = cur_len

print(max_len)  # 7
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А если не сложно, намекните хотяб как сделать это через цикл( мне это просто надо в институт, а там Pascal, но я подумал, если я на stack напишу вопрос на pascal, мне просто забанят аккаунт :)

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N, у вас в цикле перебираются символы, т.е. строки, поэтому проверка на int или str бессмысленная, нужно проверять что текущий символ является одним из `0123456789`

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N, добавил пример через цикл в `UPD`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` всегда выдает строку, поэтому условие `if type(xArr[index]) == int` не выполнится никогда. Нужно его заменить, например, на такое:

```
if xArr[index] in "0123456789":
```

Второй `if` просто заменить на `else` и убрать оттуда `break` конечно же. То условие не делает ничего нужного.

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 0):

input возвращает str.
В цикле необходимо делать проверку с помощью метода str.isdigit().
Так же можно через ord(), зная какие коды возвращают цифры.

Answer (score 0):

```
a= '12 abcsd232 df12124 5555555'
maxdig = max(len(b) for b in ''.join([a[i] if a[i].isdigit() else ' ' for i in range(len(a))]).split())
print(maxdig)
```

Идея простая.

1. из строки делаем новую, заменяя не-цифры на пробелы

   ```
   ''.join([a[i] if a[i].isdigit() else ' ' for i in range(len(a))
   ```
2. Делаем генератор выражения, разделяя по пробелу и `а` в качестве выражения длины. Ищем максимум.